# Divide the first entry and last entry of each row in a file using awk

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a file with varying row lengths:

```
120 2 3 4 5 9  0.003 
220 2 3 4 0.004
320 2 3 5 6 7 8 8 0.009
```

I want the output to consist of a single column with entries like:

```
120/0.003
220/0.004
320/0.009
```

That is i want to divide the first column and last column of each row.

How can I achieve this using awk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` will split its input based on the value of `FS`, which by default is any sequence of whitespace. That means you can get at the first and last column by referring to `$1` and `$NF`. `NF` is the number of fields in the current line or record.

So to tell awk to print the first and last column do something like this:

```
awk '{ print $1 "/" $NF }' infile
```

Output:

```
120/0.003
220/0.004
320/0.009
```

Answer (score 5):

To show the output of the division operation:

```
$ awk '{ printf $1 "/" $NF "=" ; print ($1/$NF)}' infile
120/0.003=40000
220/0.004=55000
320/0.009=35555.6
```

Comment: There is no need for the second print, you can say: `'{ printf "%s = %.2f\n", $1"/"$NF, $1/$NF }'`